# disable chrome password changed warning in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, nodes

how am I able to disable chrome change password pop up in my javascript code?
is it related to frontend or backend?
image:[chrome change password pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2wlI.png)

Comment: that warning popup is caused by the password itself is too weak or has been recorded to be breached, the warning is just telling that the password is vulnerable, it's not the issue related to frontend/backend, try to change the password and the warning will be gone

Comment: yes, the password wasn't strong enough. Thanks for your help.